# Object creation at runtime using google guice

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I am building an application which downloads the files from S3 and DynamoDB on behalf of my users from their aws accounts. Each user registers with their AWS account details in my system to start with.

When my application starts I read all my users information and create an S3Client or DyanmoDBClient for them depending on the one they registered with. At runtime i retrieve objects using their registered account details. The code looks something like this.

```
interface ReaderClient {
  public Object read();
}

public class S3Client implements ReaderClient {
  getInstance(account);
}

public class DynamoDBClient implements ReaderClient {
  getInstance(account);
}

class ReaderClientFactory {
  public static ReaderClient getReaderClient(User) {
    switch(user.database) {
        case S3:
            return S3Client.getInstance(user.account);
            break;
        case Dynamo:
            return DynamoDBClient.getInstance(user.account)
            break
    }
  }
```

}

How do I replace this factory with Google guice? Is this possible at all?
I digged through providers and assisted inject but not able to fit wither of them for this usecase. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Main {
public static void main(String[]args){ReaderClientFactory factory = Guice.createInjector(new ReaderClientModule(user).getInstance(ReaderClientFactory.class));
    ReaderClient client = factory.create();}}interface ReaderClient {public Object read();}class S3Client implements ReaderClient {
public Object read(){
    System.out.println("S3 Client");
    return new Object();
}}class DynamoDBClient implements ReaderClient {
public Object read(){
    System.out.println("Dynamo DB Client");
    return new Object();
}}interface ReaderClientFactory {
public ReaderClient create();}class ReaderClientModule extends AbstractModule{

User user;

@Inject
ReaderClientModule(@Assited User user){
    this.user = user;
}

@Override
protected void configure(){
    switch(user.database){
        case S3:
           install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
           .implement(ReaderClient.class, S3Client.class)
           .build(ReaderClientFactory.class));
           break:
        case Dynamo:
            install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
                    .implement(ReaderClient.class, DynamoDBClient.class)
                    .build(ReaderClientFactory.class
            break;      
    }}  }
```